# How to read data from any file and insert to class object using c#

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core

I am reading a data from CSV file and trying to add to object. but when i add new record by looping through records the data in object is getting overridden.

```
public static void Process()
    {
        var path= @"ABC.csv";
        var header = false;
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        var element = new List<Content>();
        var mapTo = new Content();
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var t = lines[i];
            if (!header)
            {
                header = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var data = t.Split(',');
                mapTo.Key= data[0];
                mapTo.Name= data[1];
                mapTo.Number= data[2];
                mapTo.Date= data[3];
                element.Add(mapTo);
            }
        }
       
        var result = element;
    }
```

so here when i try to add mapTo to element all the content in element variable is getting overridden.Can anybody suggest what's wrong i am doing here.

Comment: Move `var mapTo = new Content();` into the for loop.

Comment: @user11909 its a silly mistake but thanks for helping

Comment: It's only silly when we don't learn from it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Move `var mapTo = new Content();` into the for loop. Otherwise you have the same instance of `Content` for each loop iteration which gets overriden by the assigenments in the for loop.

```
public static void Process()
{
    var path= @"ABC.csv";
    var header = false;
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    var element = new List<Content>();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var mapTo = new Content(); //here

        var t = lines[i];
        if (!header)
        {
            header = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var data = t.Split(',');
            mapTo.Key= data[0];
            mapTo.Name= data[1];
            mapTo.Number= data[2];
            mapTo.Date= data[3];
            element.Add(mapTo);
        }
    }
   
    var result = element;
}
```